# Monorepo - Multiple .vscode settings

Tags: javascript, json, visual-studio-code, monorepo

## Project structure

I have the following project structure:

```
/
| - .vscode/
| - - - - settings.json
|
| - packages/
| - - - - app/
| - - - - - - index.js
| - - - - - - package.json
| - - - - website/
| - - - - - - .vscode/
| - - - - - - - - settings.json
| - - - - - - index.html
| - - - - - - styles.scss
| - - - - - - package.json
|
| - package.json
|
```

As you can see, I have two vs-code setting files: One at the root, and another one inside the website workspace.

### Root vs-code settings

```json
{
  "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.fixAll.eslint": true,
  },
  "editor.formatOnSave": false,
  "editor.tabSize": 2,
  "editor.rulers": [
    80,
    120
  ],
  "eslint.codeAction.showDocumentation": {
    "enable": true
  },
  "eslint.validate": [
    "javascript"
  ],
  "eslint.workingDirectories": [
    {
      "mode": "auto"
    }
  ],
  "javascript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always",
}
```

### Website workspace vs-code settings

```json
{
  "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.fixAll.eslint": true,
    "source.fixAll.stylelint": true
  },
  "css.validate": false,
  "less.validate": false,
  "scss.validate": false,
  "stylelint.configFile": ".stylelintrc",
  "stylelint.snippet": [
    "css",
    "scss"
  ],
  "stylelint.validate": [
    "css",
    "scss"
  ],
  "stylelint.packageManager": "yarn"
}
```

### Questions

I know that `/.vscode/settings.json` is merged with my vs-code default settings. But...

1. Is `/packages/website/.vscode/settings.json` merged with `/.vscode/settings.json`
2. As you can see, there is some code repetition in both configs:

```
  "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.fixAll.eslint": true,
  },
```

and

```
  "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.fixAll.eslint": true,
    "source.fixAll.stylelint": true
  },
```

If I remove `"source.fixAll.eslint": true,` from the `/packages/website/.vscode/settings.json`, will `editor.codeActionsOnSave.source.fixAll.eslint` be extended from `/.vscode/settings.json`?

Answer (score 3):

At the time of this writing, VS Code settings files cannot reference other settings files to extend/inherit settings from them, and they do not automatically extend/inherit settings from `.vscode/settings.json` files in parent folders.

See the highly popular feature request issue ticket on the VS Code GitHub repo: [Add ability to extend from other settings files #15909](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/15909). <sup><sub>[You can show your support for the issue ticket by giving a thumbs up reaction to the issue. But please *don't* make a "me too" comment.](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Submitting-Bugs-and-Suggestions) "me too" comments generally come off as annoying to repo maintainers because they clutter up discussion and don't contribute anything of significant value.</sub></sup>

As you already know, the settings that apply to a workspace use the worspace folder's `.vscode/settings.json` file and fall back to the user's `settings.json` file. But there also a middle layer between that: If you use [multi-root workspaces](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/multi-root-workspaces), the middle layer is the multi-root workspace's `.code-workspace` file, where you can put settings that apply to all workspace roots in the multi-root workspace.

Bonus info:

- There's also this issue ticket: [Allow folder settings to cascade / be inherited #111884](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/111884), which for some reason got close as a duplicate of this one: [Monolithic structure, multiple project settings #32693](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/32693), which seems to be more about a feature like multi-root workspaces.
- The relatively newer "Profiles" feature has a somewhat anaolgous/related feature request here: [Profiles: Extend from Default Profile #156144](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/156144). Update: there is now a "partial profiles" feature in VS Code Insiders. ([More info here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/156144#issuecomment-1640284109)).

Answer (score 1):

There are only 3 ways how to configure VSCode. Order is by precedence (first one have highest priority):

1.) Project `.vscode/settings.json`

2.) Project workspace e.g. `.vscode/team.code-workspace`

3.) VSCode user `settings.json`

As you can see we store team.code-workspace also in .vsode folder of project. We are sharing team settings in commited file `.vscode/project.code-workspace` and if developer need some project-specific settings just for himself he can use gitignored `.vscode/settings.json` which has precedence.

So if you want to use in project some option with another value then default in user settings.json you must override it in project *.code-workspace. If you want to use in project for some option with another value then in project *.code-workspace. you must override it in project settings.json