# Can I use VS Code settings to change indentation width for workspace subdirectories?

Tags: javascript, json, visual-studio-code, settings, indentation

I have a folder name called `menu`. This is my root folder. The `menu` has 2 different folders, `slider` and `dropdown`.

I want to set a different indent space in the `dropdown` folder by using local `settings.json`. Any other files that outside of the `dropdown` folder should be affected by `User/settings.json`.

I set the indent space to `4` in `dropdown/.vscode/settings.json`, `2` in `User/settings.json`, but when I open the `menu` folder on VSC and create a new file in `dropdown` menu the indent space still set to `2`.

[image]

Any solutions to fix this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Monorepo - Multiple .vscode settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72808674/monorepo-multiple-vscode-settings) (see the section of my answer that touches on https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/111884)

Comment: @user Thank you for the link. I already resolved the problem by using `.editorconfig`, but I'll look into it later.

Comment: oh... okay _NOW_ I see what you mean. You meant the indentation of the text in files in those folders. I was misled to think that you mean the indentation treelist items as displayed in the Explorer View.

Comment: can you please write up the answer you found in an answer post? (see [answer])